# Unit test an attribute directive in Angular 2

Tags: angular, jasmine, directive

I am trying to unit test a custom maxlength directive having an Input parameter. The directive looks like:

```typescript
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[limitTo]'
})
export class LimitToDirective {
  @Input() limit: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  @HostListener("keypress", ["$event"])
  onkeypress(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length === this.limit) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

The unit test looks like:

```typescript
    @Component({
      template: `<input type="text" limit="8"
                        limitTo>`
    })
    class TestMaxLengthComponent {
    }

    describe('Directive: LimitToDirective', () => {

      let component: TestMaxLengthComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestMaxLengthComponent>;
      let inputEl: DebugElement;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [TestMaxLengthComponent, LimitToDirective]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestMaxLengthComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
      });

      it('should do something', () => {
        const event = {
          target: {
            value: '12341111'
          },
          preventDefault: function () {

          }
        };

        spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');
        inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keypress', event);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
```

When I am running the unit test, I am getting an undefined value for `limit`. Why is that value undefined?

Answer (score 3):

Move fixture.detectChanges() to the top.

```typescript
  it('should do something', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const event = {
      target: {
        value: '12341111'
      },
      preventDefault: function () {
      }
    };

    spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keypress', event);

    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Also I think you need to change you directive to convert limit string to number:

```typescript
   if (event.target.value.length === +this.limit) {
```

Comment: To fully answer the question: why is that value undefined and why it was important in this case to call `fixture.detectChanges()` before triggering the keypress event: it initializes data binding. The OP triggered the event before calling `detectChanges()`. Therefore, data binding was not in place and `limit` was still undefined.